# Emberjs 1.0.0-RC3: Is there a better way to set model property for #render

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-router

The **code works** and here is the **[jsfiddle for the code](http://jsfiddle.net/M8XLF/3/)**. But, I don't like the approach I am using to get *{[render}}* to work.  For now to be able to use *{{render events}}* in application-template, I need to set it in the application-route using setupController and then calling *controllerFor('events')*, otherwise it won't work. But I have already defined an EventsRoute with a model hook for setting up the controller content and will prefer for *{{render helper}}* to use the model set in the EventsRoute.

*I was wondering if there is a better or more idiomatic way to do this in ember besides my present approach of going to ApplicationRoute*.

*Relevant code**

```
  App.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource('events');
  });
```

The {{render 'events'}} in application template  only works when i set the model via application route.

```
 App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   setupController: function(){
     this.controllerFor('events').set('model', App.Event.find());        
   }
 });
```

I would prefer to {{render 'events'}} to work with the content set here but it doesn't. But I am keeping for now to use in places where it might make sense to use {{#linkTo}}.

```
 App.EventsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
    return App.Event.find();  
    },

   setupController: function(controller, model){ 
         controller.set('content', model);
    }
});
```

The templates

```
   <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
     {{render 'events'}}
      {{outlet}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="events">

        <button {{action 'yEmpty'}}> log event content is empty</button>

       {{#each controller}}
        <h3>{{title}}</h3>
       <p>{{start}} - {{end}}</p> 
      {{/each}}
    {{outlet}}
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure of what you're trying to do. Do you want `events` and `appointments` to be rendered at the same time on one page? If yes, then, I think, you need to use `render` (much like you do in your jsfiddle). If not, you could remove `{{render 'events'}}` and `setupController` hook on `ApplicationRoute` and redirect to `events` route.

I found this [issue](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/792) with `Fixture Adapter` and looks like it doesn't work with `hasMany` (therefore jsfiddle example won't work) but I assume you are using `RESTAdapter`.

UPDATE:

Another place to set the model is in `init` hook like so:

```
App.EventsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  init: function () {
    this.set('model', App.Event.find());
  }
});
```

Personally, I would left the code in `setupController` hook.

Comment: Thanks.Yes I want to render **events** and **appointments** on thesame page. I read the link. The **FixtureAdapter** should load **has_many** if the **[returned JSON key](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/792#issuecomment-16315301)**, is thesame  as that defined in the model. In my case they are thesame, so it should work and it does from the console. But when I use the **needs api** from the controller, I can see it returns appointments inside the **events controller content property**  when inspected. But when i try to use **get** to fetch out the apointments it fails.

Comment: to make the question more focused, I have extracted the 2nd question about using the **needs api** and **FixtureAdapter** into a standalone question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16771000/emberjs-1-0-0-rc3-using-needs-api-to-access-other-controller-content-property