# Emberjs 1.0.0-RC3: using NEEDS-API to access other controller content property

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-router

I want to render events and appointments on thesame page. But when I use the **needs api** from the **AppointmentController** to have access to **EventsController**,  I can see that it returns appointments inside the *'events controller content property'* when inspected. But when i try to use that returned content that contains *'appointments'* to fetch out the *appointments* it fails. I am fetching events content in *AppintmentsController* with  **eventAppt = this.get('controllers.events').get('model');** which fetches the content and this returned content has *'appointments'* as part of its data, but when I try to get the list of appointments inside the returned  content's data using: **eventAppt.get('appointments'); this.set('content', myAppoint);**, it always fails with *Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined*.

The [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M8XLF/3/)

```
   App.AppointmentsController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
     needs: ['events'],

     appoint: function(){
       console.log("this: ", this.toString());

       var eventAppt = this.get('controllers.events').get('model');

        //This returns the correct data that includes 'appointments'
       console.log(eventAppt);

       var myAppoint=  eventAppt.get('appointments');

       this.set('content', myAppoint);

       //This fails with 'Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined'
       console.log(this.get(myAppoint));
     }
  });
```

The EventController

```
 App.EventsController = Em.ArrayController.extend({

});
```

The model:

```
App.Event = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  start: DS.attr('date'),
  allDay: DS.attr('boolean'),
  appointments: DS.hasMany('App.Appointment')
});
```

Does any one have an idea why this is not working.

Comment: What kind of model is the model of you `events`? `Controller`, `ObjectController` or `ArrayController`?

Comment: Thanks, it is an **ArrayController**. I have pasted it under the question and added the event Model too.

Comment: Have you tried retrieving the `content` property instead of the `model`? E.g. `var eventAppt = this.get('controllers.events').get('content');`?

Comment: Yes, that was what I first tried and when it failed, I then decided to try with 'model'. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking better at your code it's obvious why you are getting the error. Let me try to explain. When you do:

```
var eventAppt = this.get('controllers.events').get('model');
```

this returns an array of `events`and inside this array's elements is where your appointments are. Therefore doing:

```
//does not work because eventAppt is an array
var myAppoint=  eventAppt.get('appointments');
```

throws correctly an error because you are tying to get `appointments` from an array of `events`, makes sense?

So, if you need all the `appointments` living inside your `event` models then you should loop over your `events` content and extract the appointments, or rather something like this if you only want one specific appointment:

```
var eventAppt = this.get('controllers.events').get('model');
eventAppt.objectAt(1).get('appointments') // this prints correctly the appointments of the first event in the array of events.
```

I hope this makes things more clear now.

Comment: In fact `this.get('controllers.events').mapProperty('appointments')` is also a valid, simple answer.